# Access hatch in a wall?

Tags: building

Working on a 10 stud by 10 stud Square bell tower for my annual project. Need to create a access panel/door. Any tricks that can be done so it's hidden or at least not easily noticed?

I need to hide a small MP3 player and speaker inside and need access to the player to turn it on and off.

Comment: This is a hatch so that you can get at the inside of the tower, rather than a "hidden" hatch for a minifig?

Comment: It may even be easier to build your tower so that the top part of it can come of (resting on tiles on the lower part with maybe 1-2 studs to hold it in place), then you can access whatever you need by simply removing the top part. And, you can have additional layers if required.

Comment: The idea is to hide a small MP3 speaker inside. I just need to get access to it and the player so I can turn it on.

Comment: Then I'd say the removable top is really the easiest to work with.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest not using hinges of any kind, but just making a plain panel with a tile on top, resting on a tile in the wall. For an example from LEGO itself, have a look at booklet 2 of the [instructions for set 7094](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7094-1#ui-tabs-8). Notice they use panels instead of flat tiles which is even less visible from the outside (although they did it not for that reason but to make sure it was easier to remove).

In your case, you'll want to block it from behind (with slopes at each corner for example) as you don't want it to go into the structure.

To remove it, you'll either need to draw it by some protruding fixture if you can fit one in, or push it from the inside by another mechanism (for example, pushing on something on the top would activate a lever which would push the wall)